# Unable to update XML file on Windows Phone 8.0, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I have a problem about updating content in a XML file in Windows phone 8.0 Silverlight. I tried this code, the app runs without any error but XML did not change anything.
Here is my C# code

```
 public static void WriteUserData(string filePath, User userObj)
    {
        StreamResourceInfo stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(filePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        stream.Stream.Position = 0;
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream.Stream);
        foreach (var itemU in doc.Descendants("user"))
            foreach (var itemP in itemU.Descendants("player"))
            {
                itemP.SetElementValue("name", "12332");
                itemP.SetElementValue("high", "12332");
                itemP.SetElementValue("current", "12332");
                itemP.SetElementValue("played", "12332");
            }
    }
```

And these is the content in my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<user>
  <player>
    <name>123123</name>
    <high>181</high>
    <current>0</current>
    <played>0</played>
  </player>
</user>
```

The debug program run through all lines but not thing happened, please help me!

Comment: You have to save it after you alter it in memory.

Answer (score 1):

For updating XML file on windows phone, you have to use isolated storage.

```
IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            string fileName = "YourFileName.xml";
            XDocument document;

            if (file.FileExists(fileName))
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = file.OpenFile(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                {
                    document = XDocument.Load(stream);
                }
            else
                document = XDocument.Load(fileName);

            var root = new XElement("player");
           var name = new XElement("name", "1233");
            var high = new XElement("high", "1233");
            var current = new XElement("current ", "1233");
            var played = new XElement("played ", "1233");

            root.Add(name, high, current,played);
            document.Root.Add(root);



            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = file.CreateFile(fileName))
            {
                document.Save(stream);
            }
```

Comment: Sorry guy, but I tried and there was an exception in here: "Additional information: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream." in the line "using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = file.CreateFile(fileName))"

Comment: I replaced the fileName var with this value "Data/User.xml" because I placed them xml file in a folded named Data.